# Need to set up Network Library for eclipse in C programming

Tags: c, eclipse

How can I make network library available on eclipse for client socket programming in C language.

Comment: is it about adding library in eclipse for C, what is so special about socket programming?

Answer (score 0):

Add it in `Project Properties->C/C++ build->Settings(Tool Settings)->Linker->Libraries`.

Comment: Followed the path you provide but library windows is empty, I would like to write client-server socket and experiencing lack of header files like> sys/socket.h , netinet/in.h and so on ... how can I make use of them if they exist, if not, how can I integrate them to be able to use ones? @Eugene Sh.

Comment: Of course it is empty. You should add your libraries there.